# Где храниться файл google chrome текущей сессии?

Tags: google-chrome

Где храниться файл google chrome текущей сессии(т.е. текущих открытых вкладок)?
Рабочий профиль - C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
Как называется данный файл? Может кто подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Session Storage\

и

Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
файлы "Last Session" и "Last Tabs"

---

Current Session (содержит данные из форм на страницах текущего сеанса)

Current Tabs (содержит список URL-адресов для вкладок в текущем сеансе)

Last Session (так же, как Current Session и для предыдущей сессии)

Last Tabs (так же, как Current Tabs и для предыдущей сессии)

---

стоит обратить внимание на это:
https://qastack.ru/superuser/635436/can-i-restore-closed-tabs-after-quitting-chrome